# Shell : How to replace character only inside double quoted text in a file?

Tags: shell-script, shell, csv

I have following line in text file

```
abc|45|"Do not replace | in this"|0.23
```

I want a way to replace `|` character only in text in double quotes, resulting

```
abc|45|"Do not replace in this"|0.23
```

I have large amount of files and lines to do this replacement. Is there a anyway i could make it with shell script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `sed` substitution to match a string that starts with `"` and does *not* contain a embedded `"` within and capture that group until the occurrence of `|` and then match the second group from there to end of the `"`. Just print out the matching groups, since they don't contain the `|` character

```
sed 's/\("[^"]*\).* |\([^"]*"\)/\1\2/g'
```

Comment: The space is not part of the OP description. It works for the specific example used, but not required in general.

Answer (score 4):

New answer (2022) using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to first remove all pipe symbols from the 3rd field of the header-less CSV input, and then collapse all whitespace.  The quoting is retained from the original.

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs pipe -N --quote-original put '$3 = collapse_whitespace(gsub($3,"[|]",""))' file
abc|45|"Do not replace in this"|0.23
```

The same thing, but loop over all fields and try to modify all that are strings:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs pipe -N --quote-original put 'for (k,v in $*) { is_string(v) { $[k] = collapse_whitespace(gsub(v,"[|]","")) } }' file
abc|45|"Do not replace in this"|0.23
```

Applying this to individual files with in-place editing would be done using

```bash
mlr -I --csv ... *.csv
```

... after making sure that those files are properly backed up.

---

Old answer (2019):

Using `csvformat` from [CSVKit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), with `sed`:

```
$ csvformat -d '|' file | sed 's/| //' | csvformat -D '|'
abc|45|Do not replace in this|0.23
```

The first call to `csvformat` changes the CSV delimiter from `|` to comma.  The pipe in the text (and the space after it) can then be removed with a simple call to `sed`.  We then call `csvformat` again to change the delimiters back to `|`.

Note that the double quotes are not used in the final output.  This is because they are no longer needed. They were not ever part of the actual data in the first place, but only needed to delimit that field due to the pipe used in it (the original data was a properly quoted CSV file).

Would you want quoting of the fields in the output, use `-U1` with the final call to `csvformat`. This would quote all fields.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a nice CSV library, so this can be a one-liner:

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.filter(col_sep: "|") {|row| row.each {|field| field.gsub!(/\| /, "")}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl (sorry: obfuscating code)

```
perl -pe 's/".*?"/ $& =~ tr[|][]dr /ge'     file
```

Explanation:

- `perl -pe proc` - apply `proc` to all the lines
- `s/RE/ f($&) /ge` - substitutes `RE` by the result of  `f(matching string)`
- `tr[|][]dr`  - translates `|` by nothing (=deletes)